# How to add a profile like Test/ITG to JHipster

Tags: java, jhipster, profile

Basically I am working on Jhipster project which has come by two default profile (dev and prod), so now I would like to add another profile like Test/ITG.
I am a beginner with JHipster so I really don't know where to find the documentation if there is any. And so far I haven't seen any post about creating a new profile. I don't know what files to add, what things to change in order to use that profile rather than the 'dev' or 'prod'.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question with details on what you want to achieve. Have you checked the official documentation, https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/ ? it contains useful links to external docs. It seems to me that your question is more about spring boot profiles. If you want to run your app in another environment like Test/ITG with different datasource, you don't need another profile than prod, just use an external configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post which explains adding a new profile if you are using Maven:

https://medium.com/tekraze/add-a-new-profile-to-jhipster-application-spring-boot-application-25fa9851756c

If you are using Gradle, you have to modify build.gradle to something like the following:

```
if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_prod.gradle'
} else if (project.hasProperty('test')) {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_test.gradle'
} else {
    apply from: 'gradle/profile_dev.gradle'
}
```

Create the new file gradle/profile_test.gradle like profile_dev.gradle or profile_prod.gradle and modify them to your liking.